# Filter:Blur Firefox Issue

Tags: jquery, css, blur, effect

I tried to add a blur effect on an image + text, effects on a click in Java.

It works fine in chrome and safari.

But I had no chance to get this effect working in firefox.

Code:

```
$('.newsletter').click(function(){
    $(".overlay_newsletter").fadeIn();

    $(".name, li, .newsletter, svg, .header-links").css({
            '-webkit-filter': 'blur(3px)',
            'filter': 'blur(3px)',
            '-moz-filter': 'blur(3px)'});

    $(".menu-expand").css({
            '-webkit-filter': 'blur(8px)',
            'filter': 'blur(8px)',
            '-moz-filter': 'blur(8px)',
            'opacity':'0.5'});

    $(".logo").css({
            '-webkit-filter': 'blur(8px)',
            'filter': 'blur(8px)',
            '-moz-filter': 'blur(8px)'});
  });
```

Hope someone can help me here :)

Comment: I haven't check recently but i don't think FF supports it natively like that yet. I think they are still requiring the URL version or requires an experimental flag to be on - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: I tried the URL version, but then some of the objects will disappear

Comment: Then perhaps a short demo might be useful so we can test for ourselves. JSfiddle.net awaits you. :)

Answer (score 3):

you should set the unprefixed rule last .

```
$('.newsletter').click(function(){
  $(".overlay_newsletter").fadeIn();

  $(".name, li, .newsletter, svg, .header-links").css({
        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(3px)',
        '-moz-filter': 'blur(3px)',
        'filter': 'blur(3px)'});

$(".menu-expand").css({
        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(8px)',
        '-moz-filter': 'blur(8px)',
        'filter': 'blur(8px)',
        'opacity':'0.5'});

$(".logo").css({
        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(8px)',
        '-moz-filter': 'blur(8px)',
        'filter': 'blur(8px)'});
```

});

Beside older version of FF need an svg in order to apply a blur effect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: @A.Wolff I would myself since it is useless, and i would even drop the webkit prefix. This is up to Dennis ;) . The point is the order to call prefixed and plain rules ;)

Comment: I guess to handle older Safari version, you still need the webkit prefixed one

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf9,<svg%20version='1.1'%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='blur'><feGaussianBlur%20stdDeviation='2'%20/></filter></svg>#blur");
```

It works fine in FF, but is there a way to trigger this in jquery on a click event?

Comment: you might set your SVG into html and only apply filter:url("#blur"); within jquery http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLBVZb

Comment: worked fine for the blur. but how can i say, make the image blur on click, because the value is now set in the html url link:

"<feGaussianBlur%20stdDeviation='2'%20/>"

Comment: like this from jquery script : $('p').click(function(){$('p').css('filter' , 'url("#blur")')}); ?